# java: move files while process is running

Tags: java, while-loop, process

I have the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(calculation);
Process p = pb.start();
InputStream stdout = _simulationProcess.getInputStream();
            while (stdout.read() >= 0) {
            ;
            }
```

calculation is a call to a calculation application to run a calculation file with a few other parameters.

I'd like to use ConditionalMoveFiles below to move files generated by the process, from the process working directory to another directory.

```
public void ConditionalMoveFiles(File source, File destination, String string) throws IOException {
        File[] directoryListing = source.listFiles();
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                if (Files.isRegularFile(child.toPath(), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS) && child.getName().toLowerCase().contains(string.toLowerCase())) {
                    System.out.println("directoryListing child.getName = " + child.getName());
                    Files.move(child.toPath(), destination.toPath().resolve(child.getName()));
                    System.out.println(" directoryListing child moved to  = " + destination.toPath().resolve(child.getName()));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But any attempt to put something else than a comma in the while loop means the process doesn't end. The calculation application keeps running forever, even after the calculation is complete.I have kill it manually.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: why not using another thread

Comment: I think something else must be at fault as pb.start() runs the process in the background.  What is `calculation`? What else are you putting in the while loop?

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ Please give me a few more pointers, I have never used threads...

Comment: @Steve Smith I updated my question to answer your questions.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it?